# Parse string in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with files that has strings like this "some.key=A key is = to other" (is a properties file). I would like to have a csv file key;value like: some.key;A key is = to other

How can I read the files from a given directory and convert this files to csv with the structure I told using a batch for windows?

Thanks

Comment: with the [`FOR /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) command

Comment: I did try already but the problem is only shows "some.key;A" .

Comment: Show the properties file content, the script you used, the result you got and the result you require by appending it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Then you should check your space handling. But no code, no further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it!!

If someone is searching the same as me here is my solution.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=="  %%A IN (file.prop) DO echo "%%A";"%%B"
```

Is that simple :)